# Does every view that has an 'Edit' or 'Done' button needs to be inside an UINavigationController?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationbar

just wondering here if that makes sense.

I've read somewhere that Apple classifies the good use for a navigationBar and navigation controllers for views that really needs it as going to another pages from that current one, etc.

But in some cases, (most part of it, at least for me) is that I won't be using all the complex structure of a UINavigationController on my views, sometimes they don't have any navigation at all, just and 'Edit' button at the top or a 'Done' Button...

So my question would be?

Is it really necessary to create a navigation controller just for these buttons?
Or I simply could 'simulate' the look and feel of the bar on a plain UIView and drag some buttons over there?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use UINavigationBar in your view without using navigation controller - there's UINavigationBar and bar buttons available in components library in IB so you can drag-and-drop them to your view, make outlet connections to them etc. So you don't even need to simulate the bar - standard one is here for your purpose

Comment: Great, thanks Vladimir. The only thing is that it seems I can't acess 'viewController.navigationBar' or set the title for the navigationBar via code when its not linked to an 'UINavigationController' :( any clues?

Comment: navigationBar contains one or several navigationItems - you must set item's title, not the bar's. If you make your view in IB create outlet in your controller for navigationItem directly and set its title

Answer (score 0):

No.  There are plenty of approved apps in the App store that have custom Done or Edit buttons in custom views (including in or on top of Open GL layers, etc.) without any UINavigation controllers.  Just don't try to confuse the user with their appearance versus their function.